# Can you call an instance of a class while creating the instance of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a text adventure. I created a class for objects within the rooms. In the following code,

```
self.door = Object("Door", "There is an {} door in the north.".format("closed" if self.door.openstate == False else "open"), True, False, door_text, True, False)
```

I wish to immediately detect whether the door is open or closed, and change the description accordingly. I know that the above code is definitely wrong, but is there a way to do so?

Comment: How are you supposed to say whether a door is open or closed before the door even exists?

Comment: It sounds like you want the string describing whether the door is open or closed to magically update itself depending on whether it's open or not. That's not what the code you show does though, it's trying to compute the value immediately (and nothing you've shown would ever update it later).

Comment: Yup, I definitely understand the error @Blckknght. I just want to know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: It depends entirely on the implementation of the `Object` class. You might be able to pass it two descriptive strings, one to use when open and one when closed. Or pass it a function (maybe using a `lambda` expression) that produces the right string depending on certain arguments. But in the code you've shown, the formatting it happening too soon, in the context of whatever class is going to have a `door` attribute set on it, not in the `Object` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not a 100% sure if this will answer your question but I think you need to create a separate class for your door. I’m assuming you have some class for the room like this:

```
class Room:

    def __init__(self):
        self.door = your_code_here
```

What you may need to do is to create a door class like:

```
class Door:

     def __init__(self, door_state):
         self.door_state = door_state

     @property
     def door_text(self):
         door_state = 'open' if not self.door_state else 'closed'
         return f"There is an {door_state} in the north"
```

And then your Room class will look like the following

```
class Room:

    def __init__(self):
        self.door = Door(False)
```

Finally if you run something like

```
r = Room()
print(r.door.door_text)
```

You should see the correct outputted value.